# Time series: What is a "non-zero mean"?

Tags: time-series, trend

I am looking through a few related posts on the topic and often landed in medias res. Therefore, please allow me to ask three directly related questions on time series:

1. What is a time series with a "non-zero mean"?
2. Does it mean that it has an "intercept", or also named "constant"?
3. When a time series has a "trend", does it just mean that it trends
   up or downwards?

I considered [this post here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/44647/which-dickey-fuller-test-for-a-time-series-modelled-with-an-intercept-drift-and) but couldn't fully answer my questions from the example.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1) Any time series which have a non zero mean i.e it follows (mu,sigma-square) distribution

Are we talking about stationarity anywhere

2) A time series intercept can be calcualated based on:

[This is the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bRdaP.png)

3) If a time series has only trend, then it either decreases or increases, bu tit rarely happens that way, as a time series is generally a mixture of many components like trend, seasonal, cyclical and error component.

[A combination of these](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5nPD.png)